# MFC C++ and WPF C#: How are default directories for "Open File" and "Save File" designated?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mfc

I am trying to determine how the default directories are assigned. Let's say a user opens a file and later s/he opens another one. The 2nd. time, the default directory will probably be the same one chosen in the previous operation. I am guessing that the Windows OS somehow remembers it (in RAM). Perhaps it is up to the programmer?

How about those filesystem operations across program executions? Those are probably saved in the Registry? Does the programmer have to store the path explicitly there, or is it done automatically?

The question applies to both C++ (MFC) and C# (WPF) applications, if there is any difference.

TIA.

Comment: 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32' have some child keys, including 'OpenSaveMRU' sub-key. 'ComDlg32' means 'Common Dialog' and its MRU items are the files that you have recently opened or saved through it. I think through this data handling, you can manage what you want, however, you should consider its data was saved as binary format and managing registry is very dangerous. I think simple way is best by using initial directory.

Answer (score 1):

It may help you in WPF c#

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory="e:\\";
```

Comment: Let's say that I do not set an `InitialDirectory`.